# Laravel 5.3 storage cant find uploaded file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, php-7

I am using laravel [Filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem) to store images, the image will be uploaded inside the default storage, example:

> /home/user/Projects/mywebapp/storage/app/images/posts/1/e392e17926559e7cc4e7934f.png

I didnt change the `config/filesystem.php` and here is my controller method to upload an image,

```
public function storeImage( Request $request ) {
  $image = $request->file( 'image' )->store( 'images/posts/'.Auth::user()->id );
  echo Storage::url( $image ); // <- print the url of the uploaded image
}
```

This would print the image url like this,

> http://localhost:8000/storage/images/posts/1/e392e17c6a8d7926559e8e7cc4e7934f.png

But the image file is not accessable from the browser! 
I dont want to use php to dynamically fetch the images, i just wanted to make them publicly accessable over http. How to display the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to make a change in config\filesystems.php form

```
'default' => local,
```

to `'default' => public,`

then in console run `php artisan storage:link`

then try the above code and it will work

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I added `"../"` to the url of the file:

```
@foreach($arquivos as $i)

 <li class="list-group-item"> <img src="{{ asset('img/pdf.png') }}" /> <a href=" {{ asset('../storage/app/public/'.$i->arquivo) }}" target="blank"> {{ $i -> nome }} </a> </li>

@endforeach
```

And I am saving the file like this:

```
$ext = $request->arquivo->extension();
$path = $request->arquivo->storeAs('/relatorios', $nameoffile. "." . $ext);
```